# How can hide full path of my webpage in Ubuntu at DigitalOcean?

Tags: apache

Good day: I have my domain, for example: www.mydomain.cl in Digital Ocean (hosting) with Ubuntu, hosting.
In this path I have my wordpress files:

```
/var/www/html/alianzaWordpress/datos1
```

My 000-default.conf is:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
    <Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/html>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

I have one page for example called "quienes-somos" so I can enter like this in the browser:

```
http://www.mydomain.cl/alianzaWordpress/datos1/quienes-somos/
```

My home page is:

```
/var/www/html/alianzaWordpress/datos1/index.php
```

So I enter in the browser as follows:

```
http://www.mydomain.cl/alianzaWordpress/datos1
```

I just want to hide full path of my pages, for example, instead of showing in the browser this:

```
http://www.mydomain.cl/alianzaWordpress/datos1/quienes-somos/
```

I want to be shown as:

```
http://www.mydomain.cl/quienes-somos/
```

I am confused to achieve that, please let me know if any clarification is required, Could anyone help me, please?
I really appreciate any help.

Comment: Change your `DocumentRoot`. This question is not programming-related and is off-topic for SO.

Comment: Thanks miken, I tried that already but I got Internal Error Server "The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.".  Where should I post this question? please let me know and I will

Comment: Not sure; [sf] is for professional server administrators, not sure about the scope of [Webmasters](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/). Maybe [su] might be a good option.

Comment: Thank you miken32 :) I'll do